# Site-level fields created by the Community Site features and its dependencies must not be removed

Tags: feature-activation, site, site-creation

I get this error: Site-level fields created by the Community Site features and its dependencies must not be removed.  when trying to create a Community Site or Active the Community Site Feature, anyone no how to fix?

regards
Martin

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact issue.  I'm not sure how it came about, but I traced it down in the ULS logs to an '*Invalid Field Name {5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742}*'

It seems that my **'Number of Ratings**' and **'Rating (0-5)**' site columns had been removed from my site collections.  Perhaps due to some migration issues or content type publishing.

Luckily, my content type hub had the site columns available, so the way I got around it was to create a content type with the 2 fields noted above and then published it out.  I didn't need to use it, but now with the site columns present, I was then able to create a community board in SP 2013.