# SPException turning on Community Feature

Tags: 2013, community

I'm trying to activate the Community Feature, after it was turned off. I'm now getting this error:

```
[SPException: Site-level fields created by the Community Site features and its dependencies must not be removed.] Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.FunctionalityEnablers.AddTopicPageUrlField(SPList parentList, SPContentType[] contentTypes) +417 Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CommunitySiteFeatureReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) +1778 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce) +1769    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce) +2988    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly) +3349    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope) +207    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(Guid featid, Int32 compatibilityLevel, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope) +1212    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivatorItem.ToggleFeatureActivation()
+229    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +146    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+3586
```

Any ideas what's happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this issue raises if there are missing fields in the site columns.
you will need to check the ULS logs to identify which fields are causing this error.

Most commonly this happens when the fields: Rating (0-5), and "Number of Ratings" are missing.

[Site-level fields created by the Community Site features and its dependencies must not be removed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65397/site-level-fields-created-by-the-community-site-features-and-its-dependencies-mu)